# regular expression for replacing string in one column of text using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a regular expression to replace a string in 1st column of text file using perl. I have tried the following

```
foreach(@filecontents)
 {
  $_=~ s/($usersearch)\t|$usersearch\s\w+\t/$userreplace/gi;
 }
```

This works with the data i have tested but Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `^` anchor (start of the string anchor) and you can short the pattern a little:

```
$_ =~ s/^$usersearch(?:\s\w+)??\t/$userreplace/i;
```

Instead of using a lazy quantifier `??` you can write:

```
$_ =~ s/^$usersearch(?:[^\S\t]\w+)?\t/$userreplace/i;
```

The result can be a little faster with this second version.

Descriptions:

```
(?:..)   # is a non capturing group, it's only used to group elements 
         # together without capturing

??       # is the lazy version of the ? quantifier (zero or one time)

(?:..)?? # means "match the group only if needed"
         # (vs (?:..)? # means "match the group if it is possible")

[^\S\t]  # a character class that contains all white characters except the tab
         # the ^ at the begining is used to negate the class, \S is all that
         # is not a white character ( \s <=> [^\S] ), you only need to add \t
         # to exclude it.
```

Note: if your variable `$usersearch` may contain regex special characters, don't forget to use `quotemeta` before using it in a pattern.

Comment: I am not very good with regular expression so i don't fully understand what (?:\s\w+)?? means.

Comment: @Curious: I will add a description.

Comment: @Curious: I realize that the g modifier is not needed since you replace only one occurrence.

Comment: i thought if the (1st column of any row) had multiple occurrences of the same word then g would be required right?

Comment: @Curious: You don't the g modifier since you proceed your file line by line (if I understand well). Each line is like a new string.